How to use join_where() in Polars for conditional joins with date ranges?
I have two Polars DataFrames:

One (df) records the dates when items were sold.
Another (df2) contains additional details, including dates and
values for items.

I want to join these DataFrames where the ID matches, and the sale date in df falls within a 1-day range of the dates in df2.
Here’s the sample data:
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "ID" : [1,2,3],
    "Time" : [datetime(1,1,2),datetime(1,1,3),datetime(1,1,3)],
})

df2 = pl.DataFrame({
    "ID" : [1,1,1,2,2,3],
    "Time" : [
            datetime(1,1,2),  
            datetime(1,1,3),
            datetime(1,1,4),
            datetime(1,1,4),
            datetime(1,1,5),
            datetime(1,1,4),
            ],
    "Value": [10,10,10,20,20,30],
})

I can achieve this using .join() and filter() like so:
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        (pl.col("Time") - pl.duration(days=1)).alias("-1"),
        (pl.col("Time") + pl.duration(days=1)).alias("+1"),
        
    ).join(df2, on="ID", how="left")
    .filter(pl.col("Time_right").is_between("-1", "+1"))
)

This works, but I wanted to simplify it using the join_where() function. Here's my attempt:
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        (pl.col("Time") - pl.duration(days=1)).alias("-1"),
        (pl.col("Time") + pl.duration(days=1)).alias("+1"),
        
    ).join_where(
        df2,
        pl.col("Time_right").is_between("-1", "+1"),
        pl.col("ID") == pl.col("ID_right")

    )
)

However, I encounter this error:
InvalidOperationError: only 1 binary comparison allowed as join condition
How can I use join_where() in this case? Is there a way to achieve the desired result with this function, or is it limited in handling multiple conditions?

What version of Polars are you using? The join_where runs without error for me on the latest version. (1.17.1)

polars 1.71 acording to pip

Strange. I just tested again with a fresh install and I get the expected output.

I tested on another pc and works as you say... looks like a problem with my env so. Thanks a lot for your time @jqurious
